# Example of using the google analytics API to track subdomains

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I'm a pretty much a noob/novice when it comes to google analytics. I have asked this question in some form before, but i wanted to see if anyone could provide an example to help as the documentation for the API, while pretty detailed, doesn't really answer my question.

Scenario - we have about 85 subdomains, all of which they want tracked separately. Due to the view limit of 50, they want to do it by reading a 'session' ID in PHP (which would equal subdomain if possible) then somehow having that data either come into the suite ( not sure how that's possible ) or into a spreadsheet. They want it all separate though, as in foo.bar.net, test.bar.net collecting the different data for each (page views, events etc). So, really doing the same thing as views in the GA suite/dashboard does, but just from the other end. Is there a way to do this in a settings file that talks to the API to read the different subdomain traffic?

Thanks, I hope the question is somewhat clear

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Edited, hope that helps ( see the end )